# Reading a table when function has many argument return an error

Tags: c++, arrays, lua, arguments, lua-table

I'm trying to read an array inside a Lua function in a library that I'm developing.

When I call the function with one argument, like

```
xyz = {3, 4, 5}
setxyz(xyz)
```

I read the array correctly, while if I add a second argument

```
xyz = {3, 4, 5}
setxyz(xyz, 3)
```

the program crashes.

The problem is into the `lua_next` call inside the `ReadXYZValue` function, that crashes the program the first time that I go there.

How can I fix it?

```
typedef struct {
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
} XYZ;

// Function that I call in Lua
static int lua_ts_getxyz(lua_State *L)
{
  if (0 == L)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  int argumentsNumber = lua_gettop(L);
  XYZ xyz;
  bool res;
  res = ReadXYZValue(L, &xyz); // Problem in this call
  if (false == res)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  double range;
  res = ReadNumericValue(L, &range);
  if (false == res)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  return 1;
}

bool ReadNumericValue(lua_State *L, double *range)
{
  if (false == lua_isnumber(L, 1))
  {
    return false;
  }
  *range = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
  return true;
}

bool ReadXYZValue(lua_State *L, XYZ *xyz)
{
  if (false == lua_istable(L, 1))
  {
    return false;
  }
  size_t tableSize = lua_rawlen(L, 1);
  if (tableSize != 3)
  {
    return false;
  }

  bool res = true;
  size_t i = 0;
  lua_pushnil(L);
  double llaArray[3];
  while (lua_next(L, -2) != 0) // with only the array ok, with 2 arguments crashes
  {
    if (lua_isnumber(L, -1))
    {
      llaArray[i] = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
      i++;
    }
    xyz->x = llaArray[0];
    xyz->y = llaArray[1];
    xyz->z = llaArray[2];
    lua_pop(L, 1);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack index `-2` is the second to top element of the lua C stack. The arguments to your lua C function are also on the stack. So when you get two arguments your stack is `<table>, <number>` then you push a nil value and your stack is `<table>, <number>, <nil>` and `-2` is the number.

You need to normalize your stack so the values are where you expect them to be.

As a general statement a good policy is to use positive numbers to refer to arguments to the C functions and negative numbers to refer to things you have manually added to the stack.

Comment: How can I normalize it? Should I add the number of arguments into the `lua_next` call?

Comment: You either remove any extra arguments from the stack at the start of the function (with `lua_settop`) or you `lua_pushvalue` any arguments on top of the stack when you want to use them (with negative indices) or you use correct indices (relative to what `lua_gettop` returns or with something like the policy I suggested) to begin with.

Comment: When accessing arguments, it's safer to use positive indices.